# Kendo UI mobile cross-plaftform interface

Tags: cross-platform, kendo-mobile

I try to create a simple calculator for mobile device. I decided to use KendoUI mobile.

I set the witdh of button in %, because I thought that on different size screens the interface will be scretch or compress automatically. But I discovered that when I run the application on tablet the UI is exactly what I expect, instead when I run the application on smartphone the position of button are different.
How can I strecth automatically the content view on different size screen?

Comment: Kendo by default is responsive.. you dont even need to put the viewport tag. try to set width of button in "em" than in %.

Comment: Can you share some code? I guess you have problems with the height, not the width - Kendo UI Mobile uses flexbox which doesn't really set height on its boxes (you can't use percent height directly).

Comment: I can't post code, because I haven't enough reputation... How I can obtain the total width in "em"?